# What would make the same code produce different results in a different sandbox?

Tags: visualforce, controller-extension, production

I have this test class for a vf controller that runs ok in one sandbox but in the other there is an Id field that is returning null. What am I missing?

The reason for creating a second sandbox was to replicate an issue in production where the same error is occurring.

After exploring the results I found that when the test is running and an instance of the vf page is created, the weekMngt id returns as null after the controller is called. This is the case in one sandbox which is what is in production but not the other one.

```
@isTest
public class TemplateGeneratorExtensionTest {
  static Account accSoDoc, accPoDoc;
  static Contact conObj;
  static AVAB__SO_Document__c soDoc;
  static AVAB__Transaction_Line_Items__c tliAR, tliAR1, tliAR2, tliAR3;
  static TMS__Time__c tim2, tim3, tim4;
  static TMS__Week_Management__c weekMgmt;
  static TMS__Timesheet__c timeSheet;
  static TMS__Task__c tskObj, tskObj1, tskObj2;
  static RecordType rectype, invoiceRT, custRecType;
  static Id invRecTypeId, custRecTypeId;

  static testMethod void TemplateGeneratorExtensionTest() {
    //List<RecordType> recs;
    //recs = [select id from RecordType where Name =:'Invoice'];
    invRecTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.AVAB__SO_Document__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName()
      .get('Invoice')
      .getRecordTypeId();
    custRecTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName()
      .get('Customer')
      .getRecordTypeId();
    List<SObject> sObjList = new List<SObject>();

    //recs = [select id, Name from RecordType where Name ='Customer' AND SobjectType='Account'];
    // custRecType = recs == null || recs.size()==0?
    //                 new RecordType(Name='Customer', SobjectType='Account')
    //                 :recs.get(0);

    System.debug('custRT ' + custRecTypeId);
    accSoDoc = new Account(
      Name = 'TestCustAcc',
      RecordTypeId = custRecTypeId,
      BillingCity = 'TestCity'
    );
    //insert accSoDoc;
    sObjList.add(accSoDoc);
    conObj = new Contact(FirstName = 'Subhani', LastName = 'Last');
    sObjList.add(conObj);
    TMS__Project_Resource__c projRes = new TMS__Project_Resource__c();
    projRes.TMS__Contact__c = conObj.Id;
    insert projRes;

    tskObj = new TMS__Task__c(
      Name = 'Regular Hours',
      TMS__Project_Resource__c = projRes.Id
    );
    //insert tskObj;
    sObjList.add(tskObj);
    tskObj1 = new TMS__Task__c(
      Name = 'OT Hours',
      TMS__Project_Resource__c = projRes.Id
    );
    // insert tskObj1;
    sObjList.add(tskObj1);
    tskObj2 = new TMS__Task__c(
      Name = 'Holiday Hours',
      TMS__Project_Resource__c = projRes.Id
    );
    //insert tskObj2;
    sObjList.add(tskObj2);

     weekMgmt = new TMS__Week_Management__c();
     weekMgmt.TMS__Start_Date__c = Date.newInstance(2015, 4, 5);
     weekMgmt.TMS__End_Date__c = Date.newInstance(2015, 4, 12);
     weekMgmt.TMS__Active__c = true;
      
    insert weekMgmt;
    System.debug('Week Mngt Id found! '+ weekMgmt.Id);
    
    //sObjList.add(weekMgmt);

    AVAB__Accounting_Settings__c accountSettings = new AVAB__Accounting_Settings__c(
      AVAB__Default_Revenue_Account__c = 'TestFinance',
      AVAB__Default_Revenue_Account_For_AP__c = 'TestFinance'
    );
    //insert accountSettings;
    sObjList.add(accountSettings);

    AVAB__GL_Account__c glAccount = new AVAB__GL_Account__c(
      AVAB__Account_Type__c = 'Expense',
      Name = 'TestFinance'
    );
    //insert glAccount;
    sObjList.add(glAccount);

    insert sObjList;

    timeSheet = new TMS__Timesheet__c(TMS__Week_Management__c = weekMgmt.Id);
    insert timeSheet;

    soDoc = new AVAB__SO_Document__c(
      AVAB__Status__c = 'Post',
      RecordTypeId = invRecTypeId,
      AVAB__Date__c = Date.newInstance(2015, 4, 10),
      AVAB__Due_Date__c = Date.newInstance(2015, 4, 10),
      AVAB__Billing_Address_1__c = 'PO Box-1234',
      AVAB__Billing_City__c = 'San Francisco',
      AVAB__Billing_Country__c = 'US',
      AVAB__Billing_State__c = 'California',
      AVAB__Billing_Zip__c = '94101',
      AVAB__Shipping_Address_1__c = 'PO Box-1234',
      AVAB__Shipping_City__c = 'San Francisco',
      AVAB__Shipping_Country__c = 'US',
      AVAB__Shipping_State__c = 'California',
      AVAB__Shipping_Zip__c = '94101',
      AVAB__Account__c = accSoDoc.Id
    );
    insert soDoc;
    //sObjList.add(soDoc);

    //sObjList.add(glAccount);

    AVAB__Item__c item = new AVAB__Item__c(
      AVAB__Tax__c = 'Taxable',
      AVAB__Sales_Price__c = 45,
      Name = 'TestProduct',
      AVAB__Income_Account__c = glAccount.id
    );
    insert item;

    List<SObject> sObjListObjLineItems = new List<SObject>();

    tliAR = new AVAB__Transaction_Line_Items__c(
      AVAB__AR_Transaction__c = soDoc.Id,
      AVAB__Product_Description__c = 'Test Desc',
      AVAB__Product__c = item.Id,
      AVAB__Quantity__c = 2,
      AVAB__Sales_Price__c = 1495,
      ABTS__Task__c = tskObj.Id
    );
    //insert tliAR;
    sObjListObjLineItems.add(tliAR);

    tliAR1 = new AVAB__Transaction_Line_Items__c(
      AVAB__AR_Transaction__c = soDoc.Id,
      AVAB__Product__c = item.Id,
      AVAB__Quantity__c = 2,
      AVAB__Sales_Price__c = 1495,
      ABTS__Task__c = tskObj1.Id
    );
    //insert tliAR1;
    sObjListObjLineItems.add(tliAR1);

    tliAR2 = new AVAB__Transaction_Line_Items__c(
      AVAB__AR_Transaction__c = soDoc.Id,
      AVAB__Product__c = item.Id,
      AVAB__Quantity__c = 2,
      AVAB__Sales_Price__c = 1495,
      ABTS__Task__c = tskObj2.Id
    );
    //insert tliAR2;
    sObjListObjLineItems.add(tliAR2);

    tliAR3 = new AVAB__Transaction_Line_Items__c(
      AVAB__AR_Transaction__c = soDoc.Id,
      AVAB__Product__c = item.Id,
      AVAB__Quantity__c = 2,
      AVAB__Sales_Price__c = 1495
    );
    //insert tliAR3;
    sObjListObjLineItems.add(tliAR3);

    insert sObjListObjLineItems;

    List<SObject> sObjListObj = new List<SObject>();
    /*
        tim2 = new TMS__Time__c(TMS__Invoice_Line_Item__c=tliAR.Id, TMS__Time_Spent__c = 5.00,
                                TMS__Date__c = Date.newInstance(2015 , 04 ,07));
        insert tim2;*/
    //sObjListObj.add(tim2);

    tim3 = new TMS__Time__c(
      TMS__Time_Spent__c = 15.00,
      TMS__Date__c = Date.newInstance(2015, 4, 8),
      TMS__Week_Management__c = weekMgmt.Id
    );
    insert tim3;
    System.debug('inserted tim3 ' + tim3);
    
    tim3.ABTS__Invoice_Line_Item__c = tliAR1.Id;
    update tim3;
    System.debug('updated tim3 ' + tim3);  
    
    //sObjListObj.add(tim3);
    
    insert sObjListObj;

    ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(soDoc);
    TemplateGeneratorExtensionCustom tge = new TemplateGeneratorExtensionCustom(
      sc
    );
    tge.gettlItems1();
  }
}
```

The line returning a null ID is in the controller below.

```
global with sharing class TemplateGeneratorExtensionCustom {
    global AVAB__SO_Document__c sod;
    global List <wrapperEmp> wrapperEmpList {get; set;}
    global List <AVAB__Transaction_Line_Items__c> tlItems {get; set;}
    global Id weekManagementId;
    global Decimal salesTax {get; set;}
    global AVAB__SO_Document__c soDoc {get; set;}
    
    global TemplateGeneratorExtensionCustom(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.sod = (AVAB__SO_Document__c)controller.getRecord();
        Apexpages.currentPage().getHeaders().put('content-disposition', 'inline; filename=Invoice_'+sod.Name+'.pdf');
        //Apexpages.currentPage().getHeaders().put('content-disposition', 'attachment; filename "AVAB__SO_Document__c.pdf"');
        gettlItems1(); **First Line indicated in the error message**
        salesTax = 0.00;
    }
    
    global List<wrapperEmp> gettlItems1() {
        wrapperEmpList = new List<wrapperEmp>();
            
            tlItems = [
                SELECT Id, AVAB__Quantity__c, AVAB__Product__r.Name,AVAB__Product_Description__c, 
                       AVAB__Total_Sales_Price__c, AVAB__Sales_Price__c,
               (SELECT Id, TMS__Resource__c, TMS__Start_Time__c, TMS__Date__c, TMS__Task__r.Name, 
                           TMS__End_Time__c,TMS__Time_Spent__c, TMS__Time_Spent_Time_Format__c, TMS__Bill_Rate__c,
                           TMS__Time_Spent_Formula__c,TMS__Week_Management__c 
                       FROM ABTS__Time__r)
                FROM AVAB__Transaction_Line_Items__c 
                WHERE AVAB__AR_Transaction__c =: sod.Id];
           System.debug('>>>Called controller tlItems'+tlItems); 
           
           
           soDoc = [SELECT Id, AVAB__Amount__c, AVAB__Tax_Rate__c FROM AVAB__SO_Document__c WHERE Id =:sod.Id];
           
           salesTax = soDoc.AVAB__Amount__c*soDoc.AVAB__Tax_Rate__c/100;
           
           for(AVAB__Transaction_Line_Items__c tlitem : tlItems ){
               System.debug('tlitem '+tlitem);
               wrapperEmp obj = new wrapperEmp();
               List<TMS__Time__c> timesInvoice = tlitem.ABTS__Time__r;
               
                
               
               if(!timesInvoice.isEmpty()){
                   System.debug('TimesInvoice from tlitem.ABTS__Time__r   '+timesInvoice);
                   obj.name = timesInvoice.get(0).TMS__Resource__c;
                   System.debug('>>>obj.name'+obj.name);
                   obj.prodName = tlitem.AVAB__Product__r.Name;
                   obj.quantity = tlitem.AVAB__Quantity__c;
                   obj.taskName = timesInvoice.get(0).TMS__Task__r.Name;
                   System.debug('TMS__Task__r.Name '+ obj.taskName);
                   obj.salesPrice = tlitem.AVAB__Sales_Price__c;
                   obj.total = tlitem.AVAB__Total_Sales_Price__c;
                   try{
                   weekManagementId = timesInvoice.get(0).TMS__Week_Management__c; 

***weekManagementId here is null hence test is failing***


                   System.debug('>>>weekManagementId in controller '+ weekManagementId);
                   }
                   catch(System.NullPointerException e){
                       NullPointerException  e1 = e;
                       System.debug('Exception caught ' + e.getMessage());
                       System.debug('friendly Exception  ' + e1);
                       
                   }
                   
                   TMS__Week_Management__c weekM ;
                   weekM =[SELECT Id, WeekCustom__c 
                                               FROM TMS__Week_Management__c WHERE Id =: weekManagementId];
               System.debug('weekM : ' + weekM );
               obj.weekRange = weekM.WeekCustom__c;
               }
               wrapperEmpList.add(obj);
           }
           
           System.debug('>>>>wrapperEmpList'+wrapperEmpList); 
        return wrapperEmpList; 
    }
    
    global class wrapperEmp {
        global String name {get; set;}
        global String weekRange {get; set;}
        global String prodName {get; set;}
        global Decimal salesPrice {get; set;}
        global Decimal quantity {get; set;}
        global Decimal total {get; set;}
        global String taskName {get; set;}
    }
}
```

The image below shows the two different outputs.

[image: The different results from the two sandboxes]
I could use another pair of eyes to see what I clearly cannot.

Thanks!

Comment: The first debug statement in the image you added cuts off at "TMS_Week_Manage...", so we can't see whether that has a value.  >> You fixed it as I was typing!

Comment: From where did each of your posted debug statements come?

Comment: There's no way that line of code can be the problem, as far as I can tell. You might be barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: @Moonpie The first debug statement is from the sandbox working correctly. The second one is from the sandbox with the missing ID.

Comment: @sfdcfox the error is System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject which is thrown by the line below.

Comment: TMS__Week_Management__c weekM ;
 weekM =[SELECT Id, WeekCustom__c 
                                               FROM TMS__Week_Management__c WHERE Id =: weekManagementId];

Comment: I agree with **sfdcfox** (not that my agreement carries much weight compared to his expertise).  If it were me, I would compare configuration, settings, permission sets, profiles, access, etc., between the orgs - especially in and around the `TMS__Week_Management__c` object, since it seems to be the one not getting created and/or is not visible.

Comment: Thanks @Moonpie I had tried comparing the profiles. Let me look at the other items you have mentioned.

Comment: Also, I assume at this point that all the orgs are on the same release (Spring '21)?  Just another potential difference to keep in mind in the future for any issues, even if it is not relevant this time.

Comment: Thanks. I have checked. Both sandboxes are on Spring 21 patch 10

Comment: @Pauline, could it be that `TMS` or `AVAB` are from a Managed package that is licensed, and that in production you need to assign a license and that in the sandbox you don't? (and therefore in production, without the license you don't get the Id, but in the sandbox, with the access you do?)

Comment: @SergioAlcocer You are actually right. The app is indeed a managed package. I didn't know that is how licenses work. I will check that out. Thanks!